# How to migrate Oracle Database to MariaDB?

Tags: oracle, mariadb, migration

Currently we have a server on Oracle version 18. We are planning to migrate to MariaDB. Is there any free service provided by MariaDB or oracle that helps migrate a database from Oracle to MariaDB?

Comment: Give `Workbench` a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is certainly no such service by Oracle as they wouldn't want anyone to migrate away from their own database system.

MariaDB Corporation has a [paid migration service](https://mariadb.com/services/migration-practice/) to help migrating to MariaDB. This is run by experts in the field.

AWS has a [fully automated service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/Welcome.html) that appears to be able to migrate your schema and data, but presumably not much beyond that like stored procedures, functions and triggers. AWS is not your only option, though - other tools for this exist.

There are many articles around the web on how to do it yourself, but this will require a lot of knowledge and skills. See e.g. [this article](https://severalnines.com/database-blog/migration-oracle-database-mariadb-deep-dive) at Several Nines for a starter.